# Is there a way to have an OpenGL context inside a GTK3 application?

Tags: c++, c, linux, opengl, gtk3

I had a look at GtkGlExt, but it's only for GTK2. Unfortunately, after some hours of searching, it seems that no one take care of having something like an OpenGLDrawingArea…

Any information will be welcomed. Even if it's like "it's not possible for now".

Comment: How about using Clutter?

Comment: As described in the [developer's manual](http://developer.gnome.org/clutter/stable/clutter-overview.html): `Clutter works by manipulating a scene-graph of 2D surfaces, or 'actors', inside a 3D space.`. COGL can be used for that, as it is a small layer above OpenGL. However, it isn't possible to [use it smoothly in GTK+](https://mail.gnome.org/archives/gtk-devel-list/2011-October/msg00010.html) applications yet…

Comment: Nobody has ever tried to do this?

Comment: What platform are you trying to do this ? Xorg, Windows or OSX ?

Comment: the platform is Xorg on Linux

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It looks like you have a few options here.

1. Use an in-development [port of gtkglext to gtk3](https://github.com/tdz/gtkglext)
2. Use SDL to draw into your GTK app by setting the `SDL_WINDOWID` environment variable
3. Manage GLX yourself to create an OpenGL context for your GTK app.

I found a app [spectrum3d](http://spectrum3d.sourceforge.net/) which implements both of the first two alternatives.

The third option will be quite complex and is probably not worth pursuing.

Comment: 3. is really not as bad as it sounds